# What is the difference between "at the top of" and "on the top of"

Tags: usage

What is the difference between "at the top of" and "on the top of"?

It is so hard to know that which one should select

I always thought that ??? was the correct form

Comment: _On the top of_ = standing on the upper surface. _At the top of_ = in a high position in or on something.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.  Posting questions in ALL CAPS makes it seem like you're screaming and comes off as impolite.  I fixed it for you but in the future don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

*At X* is used when X is a *place*.  X is a place if X can be used to answer the question "Where am I?".

An example of where *at the top of X* would work is if X is a building and you're talking about the roof.  Things like hills and mountains would also work.

*On* simply means "above and touching".  That's typically more appropriate for objects and small areas.  For example, you would say "The candle is on top of the shelf".